# invalid object name after adding entity using scaffold-dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Fairly new to .net core, I just imported a database table into my project using

```
Scaffold-DbContext -tables que.optionalanswer
```

The entity was created successfully and I added it to my context class.

I then tried to access the newly added entity and when that code runs, it blows up with the below error:

```
{
 "IsSuccessStatus": false,
 "ErrorMessages": [
   "Invalid object name 'OptionalAnswer'.",
   "Unknown error, please contact the system admin.RequestId:0HLN0JGS1TMR4:0000000C"
 ]
}
```

And the stacktrace leads me to the EF query

```
var result = (from l in _db.Leads
      join ias in _db.ItnanswerSet on l.LeadId equals ias.LeadId
      join a in _db.Answer on ias.AnswerSetId equals a.AnswerSetId
      join oa in _db.OptionalAnswer on a.PossibleAnswerId equals oa.OptionalAnswerId into optans
      from oa in optans.DefaultIfEmpty()
      join q in _db.Question on a.QuestionId equals q.QuestionId
      where (l.LeadId == leadId)
```

I get the intellisense and the entity is in my project, so any ideas why this fails?

Edit: for those who encountered this, for me I added the entity to my context, as in:

```
public virtual DbSet<OptionalAnswer> OptionalAnswer { get; set; }
```

But I never also added the model builder definition:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OptionalAnswer>(entity =>
    //snip
```

Comment: did you update the database? This appears to be the SqlException returned when the query tried to read from table OptionalAnswer, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks @DevilSuichiro , turns out I added the entity to the context, but not the necessary modelBuilder definition